# Terraform get the length of list

Tags: terraform

I'm experimenting with Terraform and I came across **locals**. What I'm trying to do is to get the length of the list based on another varibale (**env**).

how can to make terrform to evaluate the variable before getting trying to evaluate the length?

This is my code:

```
locals {
  env = "${terraform.workspace}"

  subnet_names = {
    "default" = ["default_sub1"]
    "dev"     = ["dev_sub1", "dev_sub2", "dev_sub3"]
    "prod"    = ["prod_sub1", "prod_sub2", "prod_sub3"]
  }

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                      = "${lookup(local.subnet_names, local.env, count.index)}"
  virtual_network_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.network.name}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.terraform.name}"
  address_prefix            = "10.0.1.0/24"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.security_group.id}"
  count                     =  "${length(local.subnet_names, local.env)}"
}
```

When I try to validate the code I get this `length: expected 1 arguments, got 2 in`: `${length(local.subnet_names, local.env)}`

What is the trick here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `local.subnet_names` is not a list, it is a [map](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#maps) and can be accessed as explained in the [interpolation syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#user-map-variables):

```
${length(local.subnet_names[local.env])}
```

**EDIT:**

As for the `name` variable, the right way to make it is using the [element](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#element-list-index-) interpolation:

```
name = "${element(local.subnet_names[local.env], count.index)}"
```

This is due to the fact that `local.subnet_names[local.env]` will return a list. As an example, if `local.env` is "dev", it will return

```
["dev_sub1", "dev_sub2", "dev_sub3"]
```

and to get an element in a certain index in a list we use [element](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#element-list-index-).

Comment: Thanks, I now get another error :(, how would you do the `name = "${lookup(local.subnet_names, local.env, count.index)}"` in the original example it's now throwing error `azurerm_subnet.subnet[1]: lookup: lookup() may only be used with flat maps, this map contains elements of type list in`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, just wanted to point out https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/console.html is really useful when trying to work out the right combination of all the terraform interpolation functions